# Android 2.3.3, layout loading with tabhost and second tabhost not working

Tags: java, android, layout, android-tabhost, android-sdk-2.3

Below is a picture of what i want.

[image]

Right now. When i click on an item (see 2 in image) then the incorrect version (see 3 in image) shows up.

How can i load the second tabhost (see 3 in image) into the framelayout of the first tabhost?

Code right now (resides in 2, see picture) (that produces the incorrect layout) is this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent i = new Intent(StaticResources.FrameContainer.getContext(), AppSecondTabHost.class);
                StaticResources.FrameContainer.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

The static variable: StaticResources.FrameContainer is set in the main activity (see 1 in image) like this:

```
StaticResources.FrameContainer = (View)getTabHost().getTabContentView();
```

Any idea how i can rewrite the onitem click event to display the correct version? The bottom right version with 2 tabhosts as seen on the picture.

**EDIT**

To be extra clear. I create the tabhost in pic 1. When i click on one of the tabs an activity starts and that activity displays a list (picture 2). When i THEN click on an item in this list, this item will store its id in an intent and open a second tabhost inside the first tabhost (picture 3-4). The second tabhost (picture 3) will then read the id that was set in picture 2 in the onitemclick event.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using tabhost, it will automatically handle all the tab click events if you add all the tabs onto the tabhost. you do not need to change the tabview manually using an onClickListener.

below is an example from my application:

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, deployment.class);
    intent.putExtra("deploy_data", deployRawData);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Deployment").setIndicator("Deployment",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.man))
                  .setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

in this way, you are essentially bundling the activity and the tabview together before adding onto the tabhost. it should help you save a lot of efforts coding the onClickListener.

Comment: I added an edit statement. This will not work since i need to also set the id inside the itemclick event.

Answer (score 0):

```
 TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
    Resources res=getResources();

    tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("First");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("FirstTabName",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
    Intent i1=new Intent(this,NextClass.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    tabSpec.setContent(i1);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Like this, you define Intent to the tab. So your tab will remain constant and bottom content will be that of your activity.

On selecting an item from the list, intent it to next class where you have a different layout with only two tabs.
.

Comment: It should work somehow since i have an app on my phone with exactly that construction. The text Details and Photos, they are tabs just me playing with styling. I just want to display that activity inside the framelayout of the first tabhost.

Comment: If you cannot achieve  your requirement using TabHost, why dont you add buttons that look like tabs, It will be easier to achieve

Comment: Or Maybe you can add galleryview below a tabhost. Even that will look fine, these are just suggestions.

Comment: I updated the image above to show the outlinings of the things that i want. Just to make sure that we are on the same page. I'm after the bottom right one.

Comment: You want the tabs to stay constant, and only the bottom content must change right???

Comment: Yes. Top tabs stay and only the bottom content change. In this case, when someone presses the listitem, it displays a second tabhost with only 2 tabs (tabs at the bottom).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12795/discussion-between-rashmi-b-and-patrick)

Answer (score 0):

TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
        Resources res=getResources();

tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("First");
tabSpec.setIndicator("FirstTabName",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
Intent i1=new Intent(this,NextClass.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
tabSpec.setContent(i1);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

Like this, you define Intent to the tab.

Comment: Problem is that i have already set the intent when i created the tabs (at the top). The intent is an activity that produces the list. Should i reset the intent? Does that work? and if so, can i navigate back with the back button? and what happens when people click on the top tab again?

Comment: Then problem is not with your tabactivity. Does your list activity xml contain a <ListView> tag?. I have created a similar app with listview activity and tab content

Comment: Yes, a linearlayout and a listview inside of it (picture 2)

Comment: Change linearlayout to relativelayout .....that will solve your issue....with linearlayout you cannot make any changes with UI. Everything will be aligned in a straight line